# Workaround for when -whole-library is not available

Tags: c++, linker, emscripten

I'm trying to compile on an environment where the `-Wl,-whole-library` flag is not supported (emscripten). How can I trick to force the compiler to include the exported symbols ? The solution should met as many of these properties as possible :

- Could be applied on a single library (I don't want to include unused symbols from other libraries)
- Could be automatically generated (for example by fetching the exported symbol table with nm?)
- Would work with functions & member functions

I thought about computing a file with something like :

```
int x = (int)(&func_a)+(int)(&func_b)+...;
```

But it doesn't work with member functions, which cannot be casted to int (and can be private).

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

- Use --whole-library flag before linking the lib you want and just
  after add -no-whole-library before listing other libs so that only
  the one you need To be wholly linked is and try add --export-dynamic flag using a linker that supports it.
- Then dig the nm/objdump/exportmap road http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1372 to export/build link info and for using link info http://runtimecompiledcplusplus.blogspot.fr/ for using exported maps and code so that you can mimic the -Wl in your code.